# How to add aliases in laravel unique validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So, my form has different aliases than the field. But Laravel use my alias as the column name. How do I tell laravel that it's just an alias, and provide another field to use instead.

My Code:

```
 $rules = array(
        'email1'                   => 'required|email|unique:users',
    );
```

Comment: please show us the code of the form and explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

provide it as a 2nd parameter.

```
$rules = array(
    'email1'                   => 'required|email|unique:users,your_field_name',
);
```